# About the frameworks in php

Tags: php, web, frameworks

this is an less technical but important question.

i am doing php for 6+ months now and have a good basic knowledge of the language.
now i think it's time to move on to using a framework, but i am very confused about everything
(and i guess it's natural for everyone who is learning from internet only).

i want to know in detail about the core concept of frameworks in php as well as which one is good to start with. i have worked with java and have good understanding of OOP if that matters.

i am a nettuts+ subscriber and they are good with tutorials but for some reasons they are focusing too much on a framework "LARAVEL" which i think is not popular or have negative responses.

can someone with experience guide me through all this framework saga and tell me about which one is useful to learn and some ground information about frameworks.

PS : Last time i was trying to study about frameworks, i ended up reading a long hated debate on is php worth learning or not. so please guys guide me.

Thanks

Comment: +1 Some notable frameworks for PHP which are mostly used by companies are http://framework.zend.com/ , http://ellislab.com/codeigniter ,http://symfony.com/legacy , http://cakephp.org/ ,http://www.mojavi.org/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you going to start with MVC then please go for **CodeIgniter**. It will give you a great introduction about MVC in a very simple manner by working on it. Important thing in CodeIgniter is it has very good and easily understandable documentations.

If you know some thing clear knowledge about MVC then go for **Zend, Yii** which have more supporting func.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mvc and java knowledge then try out **magento** framework it has pure oop concpt like java.

Magento is build on top of zend framework, and magento is also popular now a days and you have find lots of article about starting with magento